# modf() with BIG NUMBERS

Tags: c++, indexing, double, modulo

I hope this finds you well.

I am trying to convert an index (number) for a word, using the ASCII code for that. 
for ex:

```
index 0  -> " "
index 94  -> "~"
index 625798  -> "e@A"
index 899380  -> "!$^."
```

...

As we all can see, the 4th index correspond to a 4 char string. Unfortunately, at some point, these combinations get really big (i.e., for a word of 8 chars, i need to perform operations with 16 digit numbers (ex: 6634204312890625), and it gets really worse if I raise the number of chars of the word).

To support such big numbers, I had to upgrade some variables of my program from unsigned int to unsigned long long, but then I realized that modf() from C++ uses doubles and uint32_t (http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/modf_8c-source.html).

The question is: is this possible to adapt modf() to use 64 bit numbers like unsigned long long? I'm afraid that in case this is not possible, i'll be limited to digits of double length.

Can anyone enlight me please? =)

Comment: You may find http://gmplib.org/ useful

Comment: for BIG NUMBERS you need BIG FUNCTIONS.

Comment: I do not understand why you do use the modulo operator for floating point variables `modf` instead of the `%` integer modulo.  How do you do the mapping exactly and why do you need it? There could be easier ways...

Answer (score 1):

16-digit numbers fit within the range of a 64-bit number, so you should use `uint64_t` (from `<stdint.h>`).  The `%` operator should then do what you need.

If you need bigger numbers, then you'll need to use a big-integer library.  However, if all you're interested in is modulus, then there's a trick you can pull, based on the following [properties of modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic):

```
mod(a * b) == mod(mod(a) * mod(b))
mod(a + b) == mod(mod(a) + mod(b))
```

As an example, let's express a 16-digit decimal number, `x` as:

```
x = x_hi * 1e8 + x_lo;  // this is pseudocode, not real C
```

where `x_hi` is the 8 most-significant decimal digits, and `x_lo` the least-significant.  The modulus of `x` can then be expressed as:

```
mod(x) = mod((mod(x_hi) * mod(1e8) + mod(x_lo));
```

where `mod(1e8)` is a constant which you can precalculate.

All of this can be done in integer arithmetic.

Comment: I could actually use a comment that was deleted right after (wonder why), that said:

Answer (score 0):

I could actually use a comment that was deleted right after (wonder why), that said:

```
modulus = a - a/b * b;
```

I've made a cast in the division to unsigned long long.
Now... I was a bit disappointed, because in my problem I thought I could keep raising the number of characters of the word with no problem. Nevertheless, I've started to get size issues at the n.º of chars = 7. Why? 95^7 starts to give huge numbers.
I was hoping to get the possibility to write a word like "my cat is so fat I 1234r5s" and calculate the index of this, but this word has almost 30 characters:
`95^26 = 2635200944657423647039506726457895338535308837890625` combinations. 
Anyway, thanks for the answer.